# Using the gyroscope to cycle though all RGB colours using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gyroscope

I need to have an element (either text or background) cycle through all available RGB colours using the gyroscope.

I've managed to find a few articles that relate to using the device orientation to generate values.

http://matthewlehner.net/ios-7-style-parallax-background-based-on-device-orientation/

How would I go about using this data to cycle through RGB colour values and show it on an element so that it changes colours as the phone is rotated?

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can't you just map the gyro's `X` and `Y` to a pixel on the palette (i.e. https://color.adobe.com/build2.0.0-buildNo/resource/img/kuler/color_wheel_730.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, without the ability to test the gyroscope events on my current environment, what you want to do is map `alpha`, `beta` and `gamma` to `R`, `G` and `B` accordingly. For that to happen, you should map the ranges of these values to the RGB range [0,255]. Using a generic [Map Range](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Map_range#JavaScript) function and the ranges mentioned in your link, I built a quick demo, which you can see below. I also provided to test samples to see if it works and it seems reasonably good:

```js
// Map range of numbers to another range of numbers
var mapRange = function(from, to, s) {
  return to[0] + (s - from[0]) * (to[1] - to[0]) / (from[1] - from[0]);
};
// Your event listener and logic 
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(eventData) {
  // The compass direction - will return a value between 0 and 360
  var R = Math.round(mapRange([0, 360], [0, 255], eventData.alpha));

  // Side to side value - will return a value between -180 and 180
  var G = Math.round(mapRange([-180, 180], [0, 255], eventData.beta));

  // Front to back value - will return a value between -90 and 90
  var B = Math.round(mapRange([-90, 90], [0, 255], eventData.gamma));
  
  console.log(R, G, B); // Sample output, deal with these however you like
});

// Test 1
var eventDataSample1 = {
  alpha: 125,
  beta: -65,
  gamma: -2
}
var R = Math.round(mapRange([0, 360], [0, 255], eventDataSample1.alpha));
var G = Math.round(mapRange([-180, 180], [0, 255], eventDataSample1.beta));
var B = Math.round(mapRange([-90, 90], [0, 255], eventDataSample1.gamma));
console.log(R, G, B);

// Test 2
var eventDataSample2 = {
  alpha: 12,
  beta: 66,
  gamma: 17
}
var R = Math.round(mapRange([0, 360], [0, 255], eventDataSample2.alpha));
var G = Math.round(mapRange([-180, 180], [0, 255], eventDataSample2.beta));
var B = Math.round(mapRange([-90, 90], [0, 255], eventDataSample2.gamma));
console.log(R, G, B);
```

**On a side note**, you can map these three vales to the HSL values instead of RGB if you wish, which would most likely produce a better result.

Comment: @usandthem4 try ading to that value to offset the change, so that when the value is low it is changed to a highre value, but when the value is high and exceeds the upper limit in your range, it wraps back to the lower values in your range.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. Managed to map the H value to just the gamma which has worked as expected. Only issue though, is that starts on a wrong colour when the phone is flat. How do I start on a specific colour when the phone is at 0 for example?

Comment: Ok great thanks I'll give that a try